# Create a list within a list based on user input

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input, append

I'm making a homework to-do list program by using for-loops to add input to empty lists. In my code, the first for-loop asks for the number of assignments for the amount of subjects they inputted before. That gets assigned to `hw_amount`. Another for-loop comes after to iterate [hw_amount] times. This for-loop asks for the assignment name and adds it to the `hw_list`. What I want the program to do is to automatically make an empty list in my `hw_list` by adding the current hw_name to its appropriate list. For example, the first list inside `hw_list` would be Biology with one assignment (object). And the next list would be math with two assignments (objects). Could someone help me on how I could code that? I only have the assignments going into the same list.

```
class_list = []
hw_list = []
hw_name = None

def hw_run():
    global class_list
    global hw_list
    global hw_name
    for i in range(len(class_list)):
        hw_amount = int(input("\nEnter amount of assignments for " + str(class_list[i]) + ": ")) 
        for h in range(hw_amount):
            hw_name = input("\nEnter assignment for " + str(class_list[i]) + ": ")
            hw_list.append(hw_name)
            print(hw_list)
subject_run()  
hw_run()
```

*This is an example run of my program*

*The list is printed to display to show the action of appending*

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hw_name` could be a list variable. That way you could append to it with each assignment for that subject and the append that list to `hw_list`

```
class_list = ['Biology', 'Math']
hw_list = []
hw_name = []      # Change from none to empty list

def hw_run():
    global class_list
    global hw_list
    global hw_name
    for i in range(len(class_list)):
        hw_amount = int(input("\nEnter amount of assignments for " + str(class_list[i]) + ": "))
        hw_name = []     # You'll have to clear this for each subject otherwise you have duplicate assignments
        for h in range(hw_amount):
            hw_name.append(input("\nEnter assignment for " + str(class_list[i]) + ": ")) # Append the user input to hw_name list
        hw_list.append(hw_name) # Move this append to hw_list outside the loop to assing hw_name list to hw_list. Could be done inside the loop but not worth the hassle
        print(hw_list)
subject_run() 
hw_run()
```

This is the output:

```
Enter amount of assignments for Biology: 1

Enter assignment for Biology: test
[['test']]

Enter amount of assignments for Math: 2

Enter assignment for Math: quiz

Enter assignment for Math: worksheet
[['test'], ['quiz', 'worksheet']]
```

Unless you specifically need the have a list of list, I would use a dictionary instead. The keys would be the class's and the values would be the homework.

```
def subject_run():
    subject_list = {}   # Create empty dictionary
    while True:
        subject = input('Enter a subject name: ')   # User input for subject
        if subject.lower() == 'exit':   # If user enter 'exit' then return
            return subject_list
        else:
            subject_list.update({subject:[]})   # Add the subject to the dictionary with an empty list as the value

def hw_run(class_list): # class_list as an argument, this is our dictionary which is returned from subject_run()
    for k in class_list.keys(): # Loop through all keys (subjects) in the dictionary
        hw_amount = int(input(f"\nEnter amount of assignments for {k}: ")) # User input of number of assignments
        for h in range(hw_amount): # Loop in range of assignments
            class_list[k].append(input(f"\nEnter assignment for {k}: ")) # Append the value (list) for the subject
    return class_list # Return the dictionary

print(hw_run(subject_run()))
```

This outputs:

```
{'Biology': ['test'], 'Math': ['quiz', 'worksheet']}
```

This could be a neater way to hold your data rather than using two separate lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem here is that you are not conecting both arrays. At the end of the asignment for loop you are done with that subject, so you can save that finished array to the main one, assigning it to your subject.

Which takes us to your second problem. An array is not the ideal way to save pairs of data, if you wanna assign homework to a subject i sugest you use a python [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). You can make it to store data like so:

```py
class_list = {
  'Biology': ['test'],
  'Math': ['quiz', 'worksheet']
}
```

Provided you have created your dictionary like so, you can now assign the array to the proper class and reset it.

```py
for key in class_list.keys():
        hw_amount = int(input("\nEnter amount of assignments for " + key + ": ")) 
        for h in range(hw_amount):
            hw_name = input("\nEnter assignment for " + key + ": ")
            hw_list.append(hw_name)
            print(hw_list)
        class_list[key] = hw_list
        hw_list = []
```